# Packaging a magento extension: Step 5: Contents

Tags: magento

I have a script which works on magento stores. It works fine if it is dumped on the root folder of the webstore. I want to package it where others can also use freely. I've used package manager to step 5. where there is Role: Path: Type: Include: Ignore. What should i put in these fields? the location of my file is app/core/community/magentofile.php

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a good read:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/developers-packaging-extensions-in-magento-15-explained/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/222914/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension

Answer (score 1):

"Contents" is where you tell the package manager which files you want to include in your package.  You can include

1. The path to a specific file
2. The path to a specific directory, which will recursively include **all** the files in that directory

Paths are **relative** based on type.  For example, a *Magento Local module file* will be relative from

```
./app/code/local
```

See this article for a full list of types/base-directories (self-link)

http://alanstorm.com/magento_connect_role_directories